# T-SQL Substring Replace (Translate in 2017)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, translate

At my job the version of SQL Server we have is 2012, I believe, and in the 2017 version there is now a TRANSLATE command. Because we only have 2012 SQL Server, I need some combination of UPDATE and REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE to perform the same operation as one TRANSLATE statement apparently.

My table has a SKU column, WebDescription column and a HTML_WebDescription column. My goal is to take the text in WebDescription and Replace it with 

and

tags where necessary, which is then placed in the HTML_Column.

So far... I have:

```
UPDATE TableauWarehouse_Test.dbo.EntityAttributes_WebCoreInfo_WebDescription 
SET HTML_WebDescription = '<p><strong>' + 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(WebCoreInfo_WebDescription, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),'</p>'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) +'<p><strong>'), 
CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE(CHAR(13),'.') <= 6 THEN '.' ELSE 'jfjdkfjsk' END, 
'.</strong>'), 
CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE('<strong>','<strong>') > 4 THEN '.</strong>' ELSE 
'HFJKDJSK' END, '???')+ '</p>'
```

And it returns:

```html
<p><strong>Serious Performance Bumper.</strong> Prepare your Jeep for outdoor adventures with the Fab Fours JK Lifestyle winch bumper .</strong> This bumper is designed to accept a winch with up to 10,000 lbs.</strong> of force in pulling power.</strong> It's a capable unit that offers a secure winch mount.</strong> The bumper does not feature a guard and has an attractive black style to help it blend in with your Jeep well.</strong> </p>

<p><strong>Serious Strength.</strong> This Fab Fours JK Lifestyle winch bumper is composed of 3/16" steel and powder coated with a two stage black matte coating.</strong> It offers additinoal tire clearance and is built to last.</strong> </p>

<p><strong>Includes Lights.</strong> This Fab Fours JK Lifestyle winch bumper comes with both fog and turn indicators built in, as well as injection molded light housings for adding additional lights if you want a brighter front end.</strong> </p>

<p><strong>Easy Bolt Install.</strong> This Fab Fours JK Lifestyle winch bumper goes on in just two hours with basic steps from beginning to end.</strong> Just lock the bumper itself down as well as all the accessories with bolts.</strong> The mounting hardware is included with the kit and putting the bumper in place takes just two hours to complete.</strong> </p>

<p><strong>Lifetime Protection.</strong> Fab Fours offers a reliable lifetime limited warranty on this Jeep bumper.</strong> It's protected to prevent manufacturer defects and other similar issues.</strong> </p>

<p><strong>Application.</strong> This Fab Fours JK Lifestyle Winch Bumper without Grille Guard is specifically designed as a replacement front bumper for 2007-2018 Jeep Wrangler JK, 2 and 4-door models.</strong></p>
```

All I need is to close my strongs tags correctly (ie. Application.

).  Right now it is placing a closing strong tag after every single period.

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Could you please include a sample result of what you wish to get instead

Comment: Why are you using `difference()`? And why that with literal values? Also doesn't that return a value from 0-4?

Comment: I want to get '<strong> Application. </strong>', so just strong open tags, and strong closing tags around the ones that seem like Headers.

Comment: I was using difference in order to only REPLACE the periods where there is a CHAR(13) at least 6 substrings away. But all it did was change every single period because it basically just allowed every period to change because the condition was met.

Answer (score 0):

The `DIFFERENCE` function in T-SQL is not what you expect, it's related to the `SOUNDEX` function.

To find the position of a character in a string, use the `CHARINDEX` function.

Here, I have added `</strong>` after the first appearance of a point in each row:

```
SELECT '<p><strong>' 
    + LEFT(WebCoreInfo_WebDescription,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',WebCoreInfo_WebDescription),0),LEN(WebCoreInfo_WebDescription)))
    +'</strong>' + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(WebCoreInfo_WebDescription,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',WebCoreInfo_WebDescription),0)+1,LEN(WebCoreInfo_WebDescription)),'')
    + '</p>'
FROM TableauWarehouse_Test.dbo.EntityAttributes_WebCoreInfo_WebDescription
```

I have used the `NULLIF` function to handle the case when `CHARINDEX` returns 0 (when there is no point in that row).